# Migrating beta users to prod version of an android app

Tags: android, google-play

How does one migrate existing beta users to the prod version of an android app?
I am currently running a closed internal beta and would soon be promoting the existing beta build to prod.
Just wanted to check if there are any steps that one need to undertake at the time of promoting the apk to prod ?
Will existing beta users keep getting prod updates or do they need to uninstall the app and reinstall the new apk ? 
Would appreciate any tips regarding the same

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> Will existing beta users keep getting prod updates or do they need to uninstall the app and reinstall the new apk

No, they don't need to reinstall new apk on every updates. Just sign your apk with the same package name and keystore. And changes versionCode and versionName of your apk on every update.

Hope it helps!